# Log4j2: Print logging file everyday "uncontrollable"

Tags: java, logging, cron, log4j, log4j2

I would like to print a log file every day. For example: I do operations on 28/04 and at midnight on 29/04 I would like the log operations of the previous day (28/04) to be collected in the myFolder / MYLOG_OPERATIONS_D20200428.txt file.
With my current configuration, the file is sometimes renamed correctly and other times with today's date instead of yesterday's date (for example myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS_D20200429.txt instead of myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS_D20200428.txt).

```
appender.myLog-log.type=RollingFile
appender.myLog-log.name=myLog
appender.myLog-log.fileName=myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS.txt
appender.myLog-log.filePattern=myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS_D%d{yyyyMMdd}.txt
appender.dss-b05-log.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.dss-b05-log.layout.pattern=%m%n
appender.dss-b05-log.policies.type=Policies
appender.dss-b05-log.policies.cron.type=CronTriggeringPolicy
appender.dss-b05-log.policies.cron.schedule=10 0 0 ? * *
appender.dss-b05-log.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.dss-b05-log.strategy.max=20
```

Help me please :)

Comment: What version of Log4j2?

Comment: Log4j2 version: 2.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I am noticing here, is that you are trying to configure appenders for two different loggers, that might be a problem.
Let's try to configure `myLog-log` as logger in your case:

```
log4j2.appender.myLog-log.fileName=myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS.txt
log4j2.appender.myLog-log.filePattern=myFolder/MYLOG_OPERATIONS_D%d{yyyyMMdd}.txt
log4j2.appender.myLog-log.policies.date.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy 
log4j2.appender.myLog-log.policies.date.interval=1
```

try with something like this.